# how to copy the tables of influx db ( free versione ) into postgres

Tags: django, influxdb, postgrest

[project-schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCjAB.jpg)

As you see in the pictures I have this kind of schema,
 [project-schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCjAB.jpg) I'll have many "measurements" (tables) into influxdb, that I need to copy into Postgresdb, so my django app will query the local copy instead of influxdb. i really don't know how to start, I found a lot of mirroring setup for sql-sql db , but I don't find nothing for "timeserie db" and "relational db"

Comment: What is "this kind of schema"? Please add all clarification to your question in text form

Comment: i added a link in the top of the page "project schema" thats what i mean, sorry my english is so bad.

Comment: Please don't hide relevant information in images

Comment: yes but, can you help me ?

Comment: @daner you should start searching for "data migration". I think there might be some tools which can solve your problem, but generally it is high-paid job.

Comment: What do you mean by "yes"? Please share sharing more information such that others can help you